# Slimming down polymorphic controller; where does the logic belong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism

I am implementing my own RESTful voting system. 'Questions' and 'Answers' are both votable. Votes are created, updated and deleted.

When an action is preformed on a voteable, the voteable's class is passed as a param. The controller needs to look at the votable_type to retrieve the correct votable object for the purpose of passing it to a partial.

Currently I have this logic in my votes_controller:

```
if params[:vote][:votable_type] == 'Question'
  @votable = Question.find(params[:vote][:votable_id])
elsif params[:vote][:votable_type] == 'Answer'
  @votable = Answer.find(params[:vote][:votable_id])
end
```

It is duplicated in each controller action. **Where does it really belong? How can I DRY up this controller?**

UPDATE: This is my upvote button:

```
<%= link_to "", votes_path(vote: {
                                    votable: votable,
                                    votable_type: votable.class,
                                    votable_id: votable.id,
                                    value: "upvote"
                                  }),
                          method: :post,
                          remote: :true,
                          class: "upvote" %>
```

Comment: What are the two controller actions you refer to?  This looks like it should just call a single action in the Votes controller.

Comment: Put it in a private method in **votes_controller** and call it in **before_action** (Rails 4) or **before_filter** (Under Rails 4) for desired methods

Eg:- `before_filter :fetch_votable,  :only => [:create, :update, :destroy]`

Comment: @MaxWilliams I have that same bit of code in the create, update, and destroy actions of my votes_controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@vote = Vote.find(:id)  #it depends of what is your params[:vote]
@votable = @vote.votable # it will return parent of your vote
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

---

You can wrap above code in a private method and then use it in you actions, i.e:

```
....
def update
  votable.update(...)
end

private

def votable
  @votable ||= Vote.find(:id).votable
end
```

Comment: That makes sense but it's not working for me. I'm getting: `NoMethodError (undefined method `voteable' for #<Vote:0x007fcbd412d8e0>):` when I `puts` the vote, it only has votable_type and votable_id, not votable.

Comment: Did you declare your associations like: `has_many :votes, as:  :votable`, and in your votes: `belongs_to :votable, polymorphic: true`?

Comment: Yes, I did declare the associations as you describe. Something strange is happening:  `@vote.votable` does NOT work in the controller but `Vote.last.votable` does work in Rails Console.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you passing in params[:vote]? Maybe you can change it to params[:vote_id], and then `@votable ||= Vote.find(params[:vote_id].votable`

Comment: I am now passing the votable in with the link_to create upvote so @vote.votable works now! however, I still have to explicitly pass votable_type and votable_id, or else I get errors null-value errors. I'd think rails would be smart enough to infer the type and id from the votable. Am I missing something? See updated question.

Comment: If you have access to `votable` in that view, you can pass in link_to just `votable_id` and then in vote controller: `Vote.find_by(votable_id: params[:votable_id]).votable`

Answer (score 0):

You're right, there's no reason to duplicate that kind of thing. That sort of thing can go in any of three places (assuming it's just used in one controller):

1. In a private method in the same controller. You can call that method from each action, or list the actions that need it in a before_action
2. In the helper for that controller, use a method that takes in params[:vote] and returns votable.
3. Create a plain ruby class, either in app/models or your own app/whatever directory, with a method similar to the helper method. This usually makes more sense when you have several of these methods, and you want a more OO solution than helpers.